# Как работать с easy_install через HTTP прокси?

Tags: python, http, прокси

Попытка выполнения команды `easy_install south` выдает ошибку

```
Searching for south
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/south/
Download error: [Errno 111] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/south/
Download error: [Errno 111] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'south' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error: [Errno 111] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for south
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('south')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно задать переменную окружения `http_proxy`.

```
export http_proxy=прокси:порт
```